# Convert numbers into corresponding letter using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numerical, alphabetical

I was wondering if it is possible to convert numbers into their corresponding alphabetical value. So

```
1 -> a
2 -> b
```

I was planning to make a program which lists all the alphabetical combinations possible for a length specified by a user.

See I know how to build the rest of the program except this!
Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: How are `1` and `a` are corresponding?

Comment: What should be the output if the number is 27?

Answer (score 60):

Big Letter:

```
chr(ord('@')+number)
```

1 -> A

2 -> B

...

Small Letter:

```
chr(ord('`')+number)
```

1 -> a

2 -> b

...

Comment: Thank you! For a pandas mapping for anyone else, I did this:


```df['number_col'] = df['number_col'].astype(int).apply(lambda x: chr(ord('`')+x))```

Comment: Why does this work?

Answer (score 18):

```
import string
for x, y in zip(range(1, 27), string.ascii_lowercase):
    print(x, y)
```

or

```
import string
for x, y in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, 1):
    print(x, y)
```

or

```
for x, y in ((x + 1, chr(ord('a') + x)) for x in range(26)):
    print(x, y)
```

All of the solutions above output lowercase letters from English alphabet along with their position:

```
1 a
...
26 z
```

You'd create a dictionary to access letters (values) by their position (keys) easily. For example:

```
import string
d = dict(enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, 1))
print(d[3]) # c
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) to turn numbers into characters, but you need to use a higher starting point as there are several other characters in the ASCII table first.

Use `ord('a') - 1` as a starting point:

```
start = ord('a') - 1
a = chr(start + 1)
```

Demo:

```
>>> start = ord('a') - 1
>>> a = chr(start + 1)
>>> a
'a'
```

Another alternative is to use the [`string.ascii_lowercase` constant](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase) as a sequence, but you need to start indexing from *zero*:

```
import string

a = string.ascii_lowercase[0]
```

Answer (score 8):

What about a dictionary?

```
>>> import string
>>> num2alpha = dict(zip(range(1, 27), string.ascii_lowercase))
>>> num2alpha[2]
b
>>> num2alpha[25]
y
```

But don't go over 26:

```
>>> num2alpha[27]
KeyError: 27
```

---

But if you are looking for all alphabetical combinations of a given length:

```
>>> import string
>>> from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as cwr
>>> alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
>>> length = 2
>>> ["".join(comb) for comb in cwr(alphabet, length)]
['aa', 'ab', ..., 'zz']
```

Answer (score 6):

Try a dict and some recursion:

```
def Getletterfromindex(self, num):
    #produces a string from numbers so

    #1->a
    #2->b
    #26->z
    #27->aa
    #28->ab
    #52->az
    #53->ba
    #54->bb

    num2alphadict = dict(zip(range(1, 27), string.ascii_lowercase))
    outval = ""
    numloops = (num-1) //26

    if numloops > 0:
        outval = outval + self.Getletterfromindex(numloops)

    remainder = num % 26
    if remainder > 0:
        outval = outval + num2alphadict[remainder]
    else:
        outval = outval + "z"
    return outval
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick solution:

```
# assumes Python 2.7
OFFSET = ord("a") - 1

def letter(num):
    return chr(num + OFFSET)

def letters_sum_to(total):
    for i in xrange(1, min(total, 27)):
        for rem in letters_sum_to(total - i):
            yield [letter(i)] + rem
    if total <= 26:
        yield [letter(total)]

def main():
    for letters in letters_sum_to(8):
        print("".join(letters))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

which produces

```
aaaaaaaa
aaaaaab
aaaaaba
aaaaac
aaaabaa
aaaabb
aaaaca
aaaad
aaabaaa
# etc
```

Note that the number of solutions totalling to N is 2**(N-1).

Answer (score 1):

```python
for i in range(0, 100):
     mul = 1
     n   = i
     if n >= 26:
         n   = n-26
         mul = 2
     print chr(65+n)*mul
```