# Pattern Programs - Matrix Alphabet Pattern

Tags: python

Trying to make a matrix alphabet pattern. The desired output should look like this:

```
DDDDDDD
DCCCCCD
DCBBBCD
DCBABCD
DCBBBCD
DCCCCCD
DDDDDDD
```

I have found this solution for the matrix number pattern:

Input: 4

```
N = int(input('Enter N value:'))
k = (2 * N) - 1
low = 0
high = k - 1
value = N
matrix = [[0 for i in range(k)] for j in range(k)]
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(low, high + 1):
        matrix[i][j] = value
    for j in range(low + 1, high + 1):
        matrix[j][i] = value
    for j in range(low + 1, high + 1):
        matrix[high][j] = value
    for j in range(low + 1, high):
        matrix[j][high] = value

    low = low + 1
    high = high - 1
    value = value - 1

for i in range(k):
    for j in range(k):
        print(matrix[i][j], end =' ')
    print()
```

Output:

```
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
4 3 3 3 3 3 4 
4 3 2 2 2 3 4 
4 3 2 1 2 3 4 
4 3 2 2 2 3 4 
4 3 3 3 3 3 4 
4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

Not sure if this matrix number pattern code is the smoothest solution.

Comment: You need to transform numbers in letters ?

Comment: Yes and I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert numbers into corresponding letter using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199733/convert-numbers-into-corresponding-letter-using-python)

Comment: it is the last step of my solution. `chr(64+matrix[i][j])` in your print loop gives you the ascii character you are willing for

Comment: Thank you, for the link! It is very helpful.

Comment: Hi, as you have now answers now, you may think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to reward the one that gives you the most helpful comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just need to pass from digits to uppercase letters, also you don't need the extra variables `low` and `value`, just use the existing `N` and `i`

```
from string import ascii_uppercase # simple string of all alphabet

N = int(input('Enter N value:'))
k = (2 * N) - 1
high = k - 1
matrix = [[0 for _ in range(k)] for _ in range(k)]

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i, high + 1):
        matrix[i][j] = N - i
    for j in range(i + 1, high + 1):
        matrix[j][i] = N - i
    for j in range(i + 1, high + 1):
        matrix[high][j] = N - i
    for j in range(i + 1, high):
        matrix[j][high] = N - i

    high = high - 1
    
for i in range(k):
    for j in range(k):
        print(ascii_uppercase[matrix[i][j] - 1], end='')
    print()
```

Answer (score 1):

consider it as a distance from the center of the matrix with an offset.

```
[[int(max(abs((n-1)/2-i),abs((n-1)/2-j)))+1 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]

[[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
 [4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4],
 [4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4],
 [4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4],
 [4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4],
 [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]]
```

here n is an odd value, the center of the matrix is (n-1)/2.  Since you want "1" at the center add one as offset, division converts the numbers to float format, so int() for nice formatting.  List comprehension can be converted to nested loop but seems fine this way since eliminates the matrix initialization step.

The distance is called Chebyshev distance (or chessboard distance).

To covert the matrix into a String array, convert digits to corresponding chars and join the rows. At this point readability fails

```
[''.join([chr(ord('A')+int(max(abs((n-1)/2-i),abs((n-1)/2-j)))) for i in range(n)]) for j in range(n)]

['DDDDDDD', 'DCCCCCD', 'DCBBBCD', 'DCBABCD', 'DCBBBCD', 'DCCCCCD', 'DDDDDDD']
```

use functions!

```
def chebDist(i,j,n):
    return int(max(abs((n-1)/2-i),abs((n-1)/2-j)))

def toChar(d):
    return chr(ord('A')+d-1) 

[''.join([toChar(chebDist(i,j,n)+1) for i in range(n)]) for j in range(n)]
```

will give you

```
['DDDDDDD', 'DCCCCCD', 'DCBBBCD', 'DCBABCD', 'DCBBBCD', 'DCCCCCD', 'DDDDDDD']
```

or perhaps this format

```
print('\n'.join([''.join([toChar(chebDist(i,j,n)+1) for i in range(n)]) for j in range(n)]))

DDDDDDD
DCCCCCD
DCBBBCD
DCBABCD
DCBBBCD
DCCCCCD
DDDDDDD
```

readable and with reusable functions!

You can perhaps make it more readable by separating the conversions, tradeoff is efficiency due to intermediate values

first create the numerical matrix

```
m=[[chebDist(i,j,n)+1 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
```

convert to char mapping

```
c=[[toChar(e) for e in row] for row in m]
```

convert to String representation and print.

```
print('\n'.join([''.join(row) for row in c]))
```

**UPDATE**

Finally, all wrapped up into 4 generic functions and 2 lines of code.

```
def chebDist(i,j,n):
    return int(max(abs((n-1)/2-i),abs((n-1)/2-j)))

def toChar(d):
    return chr(ord('A')+d-1) 

def map2(f,m):
    return [[f(e) for e in row] for row in m]

def toString(a):
    return '\n'.join(map(''.join,a))


m=[[chebDist(i,j,n)+1 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
print(toString(map2(toChar,m)))
```

Comment: Like the other answer, one-line is rarely very readable, when it's not a simple list-comprehension

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We can solve everything in a single input line and a single output line:

```
N = int(input('Enter N value:'))
print('\n'.join([''.join([chr(64+max(max(N-i,N-j),max(i-N+2,j-N+2))) for i in range(2*N-1)]) for j in range(2*N-1)]))
```

Explanation:
We will work in this `2*N-1`x`2*N-1` grid, for now with zeros:

```
[[0 for i in range(2*N-1)] for j in range(2*N-1)]
```

Then, we want the formating, so we convert things to string and join them:

```
print('\n'.join([''.join([str(0) for i in range(2*N-1)]) for j in range(2*N-1)]))
```

Ok, we have zeros, but we want your number matrix, so we apply this formula for the matrix with `i` and `j` indexes `max(max(N-i,N-j),max(i-N+2,j-N+2))`:

```
print('\n'.join([''.join([str(max(max(N-i,N-j),max(i-N+2,j-N+2))) for i in range(2*N-1)]) for j in range(2*N-1)]))
```

Now that we have the numbers matrix, let's apply this transformation: chr(64+k) => capital letter of the alphabet, starting from zero, because `'A'` is ascii code `64`, 'B' is ascii code `65`, and so on...

```
print('\n'.join([''.join([chr(64+max(max(N-i,N-j),max(i-N+2,j-N+2))) for i in range(2*N-1)]) for j in range(2*N-1)]))
```

There we have it.

Comment: why i am being downvoted just for presenting a different solution? i really like code without fors, it seems pythonic to me.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I can guess : downvote could be for "non-valid" answer, and there is different criteria, here the OP seems to be still learning, and your solution is not apapted to his level, and even for me who code a lot, I'd never write such a code who is very not-readable

Comment: I downvoted because complicated one-liners like this are egregiously bad practice, AND OP is obviously a beginner. I noticed you explained your answer in an edit, but my point still stands. Despite what you think, a messy one-liner is demonstrably *not* Pythonic.

Comment: Thank you for the different type of solution!