# Converting a dataset from one for to another

Tags: python, mapping

I have one dataset in a list form and I want to convert it into another dataset under certain conditions.

#### Conditions

1. `"a" = 1`
2. `"b" = 2`
3. `"c" = 3`

```py
input_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
#  something happens
output_list = [1, 2, 3]
```

What to do?

Comment: How do you get the conditions? Through `input`? Please, be more specific about details and also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

1. Represent your set of conditions in a dictionary:

```
conditions = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
}
```

2. Use that dictionary in order to generate the output:

```
input_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
output_list = [conditions[x] for x in input_list]
```

Comment: How do you do the _conversion_ or _mapping_ with this dictionary? Please explain the concepts (e.g. key-value, map function, list comprehension).

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is a *mapping*.

Your conditions are a *map*, *dictionary* (Python lingo) or *hash-table*.
Each *value* there (like `1`) corresponds to a *key* in the dataset (like `"a"`).

To represent this *mapping* you can use a table-like datastructure that maps a key to a value. In Python this datastructure is called a dictionary:

```py
mapping = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}  # used to translate from key to value (e.g. "a" to 1)

input_list = ["a", "b", "c"]

#  something happens
output_list = []
for v in input_list:
    mapped_value = mapping[v]  # get the corresponding value, translate or map it
    print(v + " -> " + mapped_value)
    output_list.append(mapped_value)

print(output_list)  # [1, 2, 3]
```

#### See also

- [Map (mathematics) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(mathematics))
- [Convert numbers into corresponding letter using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199733/convert-numbers-into-corresponding-letter-using-python)